# how to search nested document using id in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following data structure

[image]

[image]

i need to find out the document and question with a single query (i have doc id and question Id) after I need to update question with some parameter.

Can anyone help me to create the query
Thanks in advance!
Kiran Gopal

Answer (score 0):

You can search sub-document arrays just like you would search your model at the highest level.

```
Documents.findOne({'_id' : 'your doc ID', 'question.question_id': 'your question id'}, function (err, document) {
    for(var i = 0; i < document.length; i++){
        console.log(document.question[i]);
    }
});
```

Comment: HI Tom, but question is inside sectionlist > question list

Comment: Sorry, didn't see that two dimensional array. Mongoose doesn't support that. You have to re-arrange your schemea to take advantage of the goodies Mongoose has on offer. What you want to do is use 'Population': http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html